# Modify simpleJWT response

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using the simpleJWT authentication in Django. By default the response is like this:

```
{ "refresh"=""
  "access"= ""
}
```

I want to customize the response not to have a header and to contain some user details
eg

```
{
    username: ' ',
    detail1: ' ',
    detail2: ' ',
    accessToken: ' ',
    refreshToken: ' '
}
```

How can I implement a response like this using simpleJWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your own view for the api if you want to customize, you don't need to use the existed one

to create the token from from the docs
https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html

serializer.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers, viewsets, status

class SignInSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True, write_only=True)
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


class signin(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self, request):
        received_json_data=request.data
        serializer = SignInSerializer(data=received_json_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                request, 
                username=received_json_data['username'], 
                password=received_json_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
                return JsonResponse({
                    'refresh': str(refresh),
                    'access': str(refresh.access_token),
                    # your other stuffs <- add here
                }, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({
                    'message': 'invalid username or password',
                }, status=403)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message':serializer.errors}, status=400)
```